# Getting a CSS element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

## Trying to get a CSS element into JavaScript to animate it but it just isn't working.

### HTML (index.html)

```
<script src="bruh.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">.

...

<div class="circle">
    </div>
```

### CSS (style.css)

```
.circle {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

### JS (bruh.js)

```
const element = document.querySelector('.circle');
const style = getComputedStyle(element);

console.log(style);
```

### Console:

[Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLUze.png)

Comment: Try `const element = document.querySelector(".circle")` to get the first element with that class. FYI, when using `getElementsByClassName()`, don't include the `.`

Comment: @Phil I accidentally left it like that after testing for a solution. It was originally ```const element = document.querySelector(".circle")```. I will edit the post now.

Comment: I've added another link at the top which will explain why you're not finding the element

Comment: The script tag was called before the div was created in the html document. Works perfectly now.